# send imge file in chrome.sockets.tcp.send

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

i m writing a localhost chrome app by using `chrome.sockets.tcpServer` API

the app basically fetches some files from some remote url and then serves them

all the text files are being rendered well

here is a snippet of what i m doing with the text file

```
const createResponse = (content, type) => {
    var sep = '\r\n';

    var header = [
        'HTTP/1.1 200 OK',
        'Server: chrome24',
        'Content-Length: ' + content.length,
        'Connection: Close',
        'Content-Type: ' + type
    ].join(sep);

    return header + sep + sep + content;
}

string2ArrayBuffer(createResponse("html string from a fetch request", "text/html"), (buffer) => {
    chrome.sockets.tcp.send(info.clientSocketId, buffer, (resultCode) => {
        console.log("Data sent to new TCP client connection.", resultCode)
    });
});
```

now how to send images or other media files in `chrome.sockets.tcp.send`

please help

Comment: Read the contents of the file as an ArrayBuffer and send it.

Comment: @wOxxOm i m actually having a blob then if i convert it to an array buffer it sends the response but that image is not rendered. it shows an invalid image with a crashed icon